# How to save only date in Mongodb with Django DateField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models

I want to save only date in mongodb database.For that i used DateField in django models.But in database it is saving as,

```
ISODate("2014-02-24T00:00:00Z")
```

#### My code

models.py:

```
class Newdate(models.Model):
    today=models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.today
```

views.py

```
def saveDate(request):
    mydate=request.GET['today']
    date=Newdate(today=request.GET['today'])
    date.save()
    result=Newdate.objects.all().values()
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

What to do..?

I am using python 2.7,django 1.5.4

Comment: Try using strtime. something like self.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: @Anup you most definitely do **not** want to do that. Please understand what **native** dates are. You could possibly benefit from reading the answer as well if this is what you think needs to be done.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for putting up the answer,I do understand the importance of having  date and time in place.This is one of the greatest pain point in almost every application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doing exactly what you want it to do even though you don't think that is what it is doing. To explain, this is what you are seeing in the mongo shell:

```js
 ISODate("2014-02-24T00:00:00Z")
```

But that is **not** actually the value that is in the field, it is just how the shell represents it. So it's not a string value like you might think.

Internally the value in the field is a [BSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) date, which is a specially tagged version of an epoch time value. This is **very** useful, and what you really want, as it is considered by the server to be a proper date, and can be compared to other date values, have different date operations performed on it, etc.

Also just as your application "just saved this" from supplying a native date object, when this is read back from the collection you will **also** get a **native** date object.

What **not** to do, is convert these to strings in your application, and thus have to convert back when you *read* the data.

Stick to using the native dates, it's what you really want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes you are right, When i am retrieving the date from mongodb i am getting only date in date format like 'datetime.datetime(2014,02,24)`

Comment: And how to display only date in the html page,I am getting `datetime.date(2014, 2, 14)` this.I dont want to display datetime.date.Can you help me